# Chartboost Integration; src files and Google Play Services Library problems

Tags: apk, google-play-services, chartboost

I have finished creating an Android app and have decided to monetize it with Chartboost. I am currently following the implementation guide found here: https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/android#android-detailed. Using eclipse I have followed the steps up until the src where you add the code "import com.chartboost.sdk.*;" (no quotations). My other problem is the Google Play Services Library integration similar to the other one. I am supposed to edit the build.gradle which I do not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build.gradle file is something you create as a part of the app creation - if you choose. The reference made in the guide is to that file (created by you) and not part of the SDK.

[You can find data on Gradle here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/)